# Coupled current in shield in a tube from a transient surge

Tags: inductance, transient, surge-protection, coupling

If a shielded cable (B) is running inside the centre of a tubular structure (A), how is the coupled current from a surge estimated in the shield?

I am trying to figure out how the coupled current between a structure, such as a tower, and a shielded signal cable can be estimated during a surge. I have been trying to do some research but without much luck.

To clarify the question, the example inputs could be:

- Length L = 200m
- Radius R = 1m
- Surge current I_A = 200kA (10/350)µs
- Diameter of cable shield = 8mm
- Both A and B are terminated to a common node at the ground (Not shown in drawing)
- The medium between the conductors is air

[image],